# Stata: mean by ID and subset

Tags: stata

In Stata, I have a panel data set with panel identifiers and a time variable (and the metrics of interest). I would like to generate a variable that is equal to the mean of one of those metrics over a specific range of years, by panel ID. Doing the following does what I want, but only populates the variable for the years I restrict it to. I'd like that result to be populated for all the years. I have jury-rigged a solution involving sorting the data, but I wanted to check if there was a more elegant approach.

```
sort id year
egen x_natural = mean(x) if year >= 2005 & year <= 2007, by(id)
sort id x_natural year
replace x_natural = x_natural[_n-1] if id == id[_n-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is

```
egen x_natural = mean(x / (year >= 2005 & year <= 2007)), by(id)
```

and another is

```
egen x_natural = mean(cond(year >= 2005 & year <= 2007, x, .)), by(id)
```

Incidentally,

```
year >= 2005 & year <= 2007
```

can be calculated using

```
inrange(year, 2005, 2007)
```

For a fairly systematic introductory survey of this territory, see http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 which is now accessible to all as a .pdf. 
For that directly, see http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055

Comment: Interesting! One question: what's going on in your first suggestion? It appears that you're dividing x by a binary variable equal to 1 when in my range and 0 when outside of it. Why doesn't this return an error for the outside-range years?

Comment: It's all explained in my paper. That's accessible to you, as I emphasised, so I suggest you read it.